# Facebook user and fan page activities using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I tried a lot on graph explorer and writing some php scripts to get the data but badly stuck on this

So my question is what is the replacement of FQL in v2.1
There were good days when I made some adhoc queries to facebook and the magic use to happen.
Now I am badly stuck with the committements to client and not able to successfully fill the gaps

In the kingdom of FQL

```
$query = "SELECT post_id, user_id FROM like 
            WHERE  
            post_id 
            IN 
            ( 
                SELECT post_id FROM stream 
                WHERE 
                source_id = \"".stripcslashes( trim( $fan_page_id ) )."\"
            ) 
            AND 
            user_id= \"".stripcslashes( trim ( $fb_user_id ) )."\"";
```

I use to get all the data that depicted the Like interaction of the user on particular fan page posts

```
$query = "SELECT text, likes, time, comment_count, parent_id, fromid FROM comment 
            WHERE  
            post_id 
            IN 
            (   SELECT post_id FROM stream 
                WHERE 
                source_id =\"".stripcslashes( trim( $fan_page_id ) )."\"
            ) 
            AND 
            fromid= \"".stripcslashes( trim( $fb_user_id ) )."\"";
```

The similar way for comments on posts

```
$query = "SELECT actor_id, post_id, type, message, created_time, attachment, like_info, share_info, comment_info FROM stream
            WHERE
            source_id = \"".stripcslashes( trim( $fan_page_id ) )."\"
            AND
            actor_id = \"".stripcslashes( trim ( $fb_user_id ) )."\"";
```

But with the Graph Api v2.1 I dont know how should go about rewriting these queries again 
As these queries as simple has all analytics done in nutshell to evaluate the user interaction and assign points.

I tried with one of the queries by getting all list of post ids on a fan page and then on each id get likes and then storing in temporary list all the user ids equal to fb user id.

But thats a bad way of doing it and its quiet costly on the server just fetching this information alone takes approx 10 to 20 secs and that too limited data of just 5 posts with couples of likes.

I dont know how to go about with this 
Can someone tell me any hack to solve this problem